# Client to Server Messaging- Java

Tags: java, client

I would like some input on my relatively simple Client to server messaging program.

I think the Client part is OK, but the server bit is a bit broken.

The program actually sort of works (client can send messages to server).

I am having trouble putting a username + password on it (set it up for a default password + username , not storing multiple usernames + password) (currently using username:1, password:2).

And I would like for the server the receive the clients Ip, when it connects, if anyone has any spare time and some java experience it would be greatly appreciated.

Client:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class LongClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
            Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.flush();

            String message, servermessage;
            InetAddress clientip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Preparing to chat...");
            out.println("Client IP Address: " + clientip); // sends message to client giving ip
            out.println("Client hostname: " + clientip.getHostAddress()); // send message to client giving computer name

            do {
                if (in.ready()) {
                    servermessage = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println("server>: " + servermessage);
                }

                message = kbReader.nextLine();
                out.println(message);

                out.println("Done");

                //message="bye";
                //out.println("bye");
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
            } while (!message.equals("bye"));

            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    } 
}
```

Server:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class LongServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String data = "Welcome to My Server"; //welcome message
        String data1 = "enter username"; //welcome message
        String message; 

        int idstats1 = 0; //verifyed username
        int idstats2 = 0; //verifyed password 
        int verify1 = 0;
        try {
            //Detecting the localhost's ip address
            InetAddress localaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println ("Local IP Address : " + localaddr );
            System.out.println ("Local hostname : " + localaddr.getHostAddress());

            //Creating a server socket for connection
            ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234);
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection on "+localaddr);

            //Accept incoming connection
            Socket skt = srvr.accept();
            System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");

            //get Input and Output streams
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.flush();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
            System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data + "'\n");
            out.println(data); //sends welcome message
            System.out.print("Sending string: '" + data1 + "'\n");
            out.println(data1); //sends welcome message

            message = in.readLine(); //reads the line typed in
            while(verify1 == 0) {
                if (idstats1 == 0) {
                    //if the client is not verifyed, it asks for a password
                    out.println("enter username");
                }
                if (idstats2 == 0) {
                    //if the client is not verifyed, it asks for a password
                    out.println("enter password");
                }

                if (message.equals("1")) { 
                    //is the input is password, then the client is verifyed
                    out.println("Username accepted");
                    idstats1 = 1;    
                }
                if (message.equals("2")) { 
                    //is the input is password, then the client is verifyed
                    out.println("Password Accepted");
                    idstats2 = 1;    
                }
                if (idstats1 == 1 && idstats2 == 1) {
                    verify1 = 1;
                }                           
            }

            if (verify1 == 1) {
                //if client is verifyed, it asks them to type a message and prints it to the console
                out.println("enter a message");
                System.out.println("client>"+message);
            }
            if (message.equals("bye")) { 
                //if the client enters "bye" then the server closes
                out.println("Server closing");
                System.out.println("server>Server closing");
            }
            while(!message.equals("bye")); {
                out.close();
                skt.close();
                srvr.close();
            }
        } catch(BindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("A server is already running on the same port.");        
        } catch(SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Client has disconnected rudely.");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e);    
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is some strange thing about your code - `while(!message.equals("bye")); {` in `Server` won't compile :( Can you please fix it? Looks like you forgot `do {`.

Comment: If you ask me, it seems like you needs a higher-level stream.You should look into `ObjectOutputStream`. This will allow you to send instaces instead of just primitives. This way, you can create a different classes (for different types), which contain info. You can create a new instance of that class, store data in it, and send it over. When you receive the object (in.readObject()), you can use `instanceof` to switch between which class type. This way you can have LoginPacket.java and MessagePacket.java

Comment: @AlexeyMalev  Thats for looking at it, I think if I just take it out for now then worry about  it later would be good, the line of code works on the client side, but not on the server side, to me that indicates that there is a problem sending the message, what do you think?